# yfinance select one day

Tags: python, yfinance

I'm trying to just get one day's worth of data for a specific date, but yfinance keeps returning the start date to current instead of just 1 day. I've tried the following (gives startdate to present)

```
data = yf.Ticker(symbol)
today_data = data.history(period='1d',start=startdate)
```

and (also gives startday to present)

```
data = yf.Ticker(symbol)
today_data = data.history(interval='1d',period='1d',start=startdate)
```

and (gives an error)

```
data = yf.Ticker(symbol)
today_data = data.history(period='1d',start=startdate,end=startdate)
```

Comment: What error does the last example give?

Comment: Specify the market business day as the start date or an error will occur. If I specify the start date as a market business day and the end date as a non-business day, the error does not occur. For example, if you want to retrieve only Fridays. `data = yf.download("AAPL", start="2023-03-31", end="2023-04-01", period='1d')`